# date from jQuery datepicker returning NaN in IE while returning value in Chrome; breaking AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, datepicker

This:

```
var form_date = new Date($('#datepicker').val());
var date = $.datepicker.formatDate('m', form_date);
```

is correctly returning the numerical value of a given month via jQuery datepicker in Chrome while it's returning NaN in Internet Explorer, which causes an incorrect query via AJAX ... how is this solved to function in both Chrome and IE?

Comment: which version of jQuery and IE are u using